# EWS Retrieve oldest unread emails not working

Tags: vb.net, exchangewebservices

I need the last 5 unread emails.  I can get unread emails but cannot get it to sort by datetime recevied descending.  Please see my code below:

```
Dim iv = New ItemView(5) ' get last 5 emails

iv.OrderBy.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, SortDirection.Descending)

Dim sf As SearchFilter = New SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And,_
    New SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, False))

Dim emails = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, sf, iv)
```

**More information:**
I need to process the oldest email first.

If i do not use searchfilter, it works as expected with the oldest emails coming up first.  But if i use the searchfilter, it ignores the sort order.  I have removed my extra search filters as they are not causing a problem.

Comment: Never used EWS before, but I just tried out your code and the sorting seems to be working as expected.

Comment: The default Sort order is descending eg the latest emails will be returned first so the results your describing don't really make sense. Also why are using a SearchFilter collection when you only have one SearchFilter

Comment: I have added more information, without searchfilter and the view descending will show the older emails.  But searchfilter seems to ignore my view order.  I have other search filters that are excluded from the example as not causing the problem.

Comment: If you want the Oldest email first then your sort order should be ascending http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting eg time in linear so the future is greater then the past.

Comment: Thanks, ascending does work with the search filter, what confused me was that descending worked the same without the search filter.  not sure why having a search filter reversed the sorting mechanism.